# How to slice every array that are within an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example this array

```
  var array=  [
    [1,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"...],
    [2,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"...],
    [3,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"...],
    [4,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"...]...
    ];
```

I want to slice every array to generate a new one like this with slice(0,3)

```
var resultSecondArray=[
        [1,"dataA","dataB"],
        [2,"dataA","dataB"],
        [3,"dataA","dataB"],
        [4,"dataA","dataB"]...
];
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a forEach() loop or map() and simply push the sliced original array items into the second array.

```js
var array=  [
    [1,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"],
    [2,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"],
    [3,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"],
    [4,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"]
    ];
    

var resultSecondArray= [];

array.forEach (function(arr){
  resultSecondArray.push(arr.slice(0,3));
})

console.log(resultSecondArray); // gives [[1, "dataA","dataB"],[2, "dataA","dataB"],[ 3, "dataA", "dataB"],[ 4,"dataA", "dataB"]]
```

Using a map() to get the  same result

```js
let array=  [
    [1,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"],
    [2,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"],
    [3,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"],
    [4,"dataA","dataB","dataC","dataD"]
    ];
    

let resultSecondArray= array.map(arr => arr.slice(0,3));

console.log(resultSecondArray); // gives [[1, "dataA","dataB"],[2, "dataA","dataB"],[ 3, "dataA", "dataB"],[ 4,"dataA", "dataB"]]
```

Comment: I started learning ES6+ and i'm new with those functions,thanks gavgrif